# Show server busy only for requests without cookie

Tags: nginx, apache2, varnish, vcl, http-status-code-503

I have a website that is frequently overloaded with multiple requests from thousands of clients. I cannot scale to infinity my servers and the application in current state is not possible to handle the traffic. For a better comfort I would like to let firstly the clients that started the transaction to complete it, and after that allow other clients to start the transaction. I am looking for a solution how to divide HTTP requests to two groups: the first requests that are able to finish the transaction and the others that should receive the 503 Server busy web page.

I can handle some amount of transactions concurrently. The rest transactions I would like to hold for a while with Server busy web page. I thought that I can use varnish for that. Bud I cannot think up the right condition in VCL for that.

I would like to find in varnish the number of current connections to the backend. If the current number of connections will be higher than some value (eg. 100) and the request didn't have a session cookie, the response will be 503 Server busy. If the number of connections will even greater than 100, but the session cookie exists, the requests will be passed to the backend.

AFAIK in varnish VCL I can get only the health of the backend (director) that should be true/false. But when backend is considered not healthy, the requests are not passed to it. When I use max_connections to the backend, all connections up to the limit will got 503 error.

Is there a way how to achive this behavior with varnish, ngingx, apache or any other tool?

Answer (score 0):

Does your content have to be dynamic no matter what? I run a site that handles 3 to 4 million unique a day and use features like grace mode to handle invalidation.

Maybe another option is ESI, Edge Side Includes, that may help reduce load by caching everything that isn't dynamic.

Comment: It is tickets selling website - many concurrent requests in a short time. The application logic is written mainly in the SQL procedures. Yes there are some parts that should be cached, but when the user will choose his seat, the transaction should be as smooth as possible. The infrastructure and the application is able to serve smoothly only few hundreds (maybe 1000) concurrent requests, therefor I am looking for a solution, how to hold some clients for a short while with 503 Server busy page.